# Does using a function to call http.get have advantages over directly assigning the call to a variable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When building a service in Angular is there any advantage of using a method to return an observable from http.get rather than assigning the observable to a variable directly on the service.

For example does: `getPerson = () => this.http.get<Person>(personUrl);`

have any advantages over: `person$ = this.http.get<Person>(personUrl);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benefit of using a method: It is easier to pass parameters for parameterized queries. Using the declarative approach means that you need to use a signal or a Subject/BehaviorSubject to react to the parameter and issue the http get request.

Benefit of a declarative approach (just using a variable): It is easier to work with the variable. You can use other operators, such as `combineLatest`. You can more easily pipe the result through additional operators in any of the components to do component-level sorting.

Here are two examples:

EXAMPLE ONE: Combining two observables to "look up" the category ID and add a category name for display in the UI:

```
  productsWithCategory$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,
    this.productCategoryService.productCategories$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, categories]) =>
      products.map(product => ({
        ...product,
        category: categories.find(c => product.categoryId === c.id)?.name
      } as Product))
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

EXAMPLE TWO: Finding a specific product in the array of products returned from the http.get of all products.

```
  private productSelectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  productSelectedAction$ = this.productSelectedSubject.asObservable();

  selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([
    this.productsWithCategory$,
    this.productSelectedAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, selectedProductId]) =>
      products.find(product => product.id === selectedProductId)
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Also, in future versions of Angular, it may be easier to use the declarative approach and then create a signal from the result using the new signal features for binding to the UI.

```
  products = toSignal(this.products$, {initialValue: [] as Product[]});
```

Comment: I think this makes the most sense. I think being consistent is more important than minimizing the few lines of code it takes to define a method. Since some requests need parameters then it makes it more readable and easier to maintain if that pattern is followed for all http calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In both cases observable is cold and will be executed on every subscription.

But, as a general rule, use function or method if observable is cold, Your code will be more readable. For almost every API call there is some parameters, so you will explicitly create new observable by calling method with request parameters. Why make exclusion for this one?